# Access member of outer type from inner type

Tags: f#, xunit

I am wondering what I have to do in order to make the following F# code compile:

```
type MyType() =
  [<Literal>]
  let outer = "Foo"

  type MyInnerType() =
    [<Literal>]
    let inner = outer + ".Bar"
```

The compiler raises the error FS0039 "The value or constructor 'outer' is not defined". Is this something which should not be possible or is disallowed by design?

I want to use these value in a attribution of a xUnit test method which requires the values to be compile-time constants (thus `[<Literal>]`):

```
    [<Trait("", inner)>]
    [<Fact>]
    let test() =
      Assert.Equal(3, 1 + 2)
```

Comment: The reason you can't see `outer` from `MyInnerType` is that the compiler effectively sees `outer` as a local variable in the constructor of `MyType`, and so, in the IL that is generated, the `outer` binding won't even exist.  Since there are no references to the binding in `MyType`, it is completely optimized away.  If you were to have a property or method in `MyType` that referenced `outer`, then the value of outer would be copied into that property or method directly, but the actual binding will still be erased.

Comment: Another thing to note is that simply having the `MyInnerType` class idented like a member of `MyType` does not make it an inner class in F#.  F# does not support nested classes.

Comment: @AaronM.Eshbach Is there a way to make `outer` `public` instead of `private`?

Comment: Can you put your literals in a module instead of in the classes?

Comment: Since I learned that F# does not support nested classes I am fine with implementing it with modules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What may probably work for you is literal expressions working across F# [modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/modules). The following snippet

```
module A =
    [<Literal>]
    let A = "A"

    module B =
        [<Literal>]
        let B = A + "B"

[<Literal>]
let C = A.A + A.B.B + "C"
```

fsi consumes as

```
module A = begin
  val A : string = "A"
  module B = begin
    val B : string = "AB"
  end
end
val C : string = "AABC"
```

meaning that F# compiler is happy composing literals and constant expressions from different modules, maybe nested, into a constant expression.

Comment: Can modules be nested so that I can omit `A.` and only write `A` in a module `Z` nested into module `A`?

Comment: @David Yes, they can be nested this way. I've modified my snippet to demonstrate such composition.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that outer is a class field, so you need to instantiate the class before referencing its internals.

This might work for you:

```
type MyType() =
  static member outer = "Foo"

  type MyInnerType() =
    let inner = MyType.outer + "Bar"
```

Comment: I wanted `outer` to be what would be written in C# a `const string outer` and therefore a static member.